# Ionic 3 button is not appearing after a user logged in and a global variable changed according to its condition

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In my app.component.ts, I added the side menu where it contain all pages. For the login/Registration page, I've added the following script:

```
<button menuClose ion-item (click)="authenticate()" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
    <ion-icon name="log-in"></ion-icon> Login/Register
</button>
<button menuClose ion-item (click)="logout()" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
    <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon> Logout
</button>
```

As you see, if the variable `isLoggedIn` is false, the `login` should appear, else, a logout button is displayed.

When a user is logged in and a `user_id` is set in the storage, and the isLoggedIn changed to true, the logout button does not appear.

Here is the login script:

```
if (response && response.status === 'success') {
    console.log(response.response.user_id);
    this.globalVar.loggedIn=true;
    // localStorage.setItem('user_id', response.data.user_id)
    this.storage.set('user_id', response.response.user_id);
    this.storage.set('fname', response.response.fname);
    this.storage.set('lname', response.response.lname);
    this.storage.set('email', response.response.email);
    loading.dismiss();
    this.storage.get('user_id').then((data)=>{
      this.globalVar.user_id=data
    });
    this.storage.get('fname').then((data)=>{
      this.globalVar.fname=data
    });
    this.storage.get('lname').then((data)=>{
      this.globalVar.lname=data
    });
    this.storage.get('email').then((data)=>{
      this.globalVar.email=data
    });
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    let dataToSend={
      'offer_id': this.offer_id,
      'offerSelected': this.offerSelected,
      'user_id': this.globalVar.user_id
    };
    if(this.offerSelected && this.offer_id!='')
    {
      this.navCtrl.push(OfferDetailsPage, {
        data: dataToSend
      })
    }

  }
    else if (response && response.status == 'failed') {
      this.message = response.message;
      loading.dismiss();
    }
    else
    {
      this.message = 'Server is currently unavailable'
      loading.dismiss();
    }
  }, (error) => {
    loading.dismiss();
    this.showAlert(error.message);
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

I consoled the isLoggedIn and it is true.

Answer (score 0):

That is some really messy code, from what I can see you are not referring to the correct variable name or you are just not showing all the code required to receive any assistance from the community here.

You set the variable "this.globalVar.loggedIn=true;"

And your if statements are looking at a variable named "isLoggedIn"

Where is the variable isLoggedIn defined? This is probably in your controller file, which then loads the ion-view that has your buttons with the if statements on them.